# I couldnt make the super constructor

Tags: java

I have a Human class
[Human.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKVoV.png)

Also I have a Teacher class

[Teacher.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaddR.png)

But i couldnt add the super constructor to my Retired_teacher

```
public class Retired_teacher extends Teacher{

 public int retirement_year;

 Retired_teacher(Teacher t, int ry_){

     super Teacher(name,surname,age,gender);  
     String na=get_name();
    System.out.println("A new teacher " + na + " " + surname + "is constructed");
    System.out.println("A teacher is retired");
    retirement_year=ry_;
```

super is making error how can i fix this

Comment: Add your codes instead of posting images.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `super` wrong, you should just call:

```
super(name,surname,age,gender);
```

No need for the class name.

Also in your `Teacher` class the constructor is taking **5** arguments, and here you are just supplying **4**. So take that in mind, this won't work unless you add another argument.

Comment: That didnt fix it either

Comment: This is 100% correct. You didn't say what your error is even. **Edit** your question with your complete error (attach stack trace) and specify what isn't working.

Comment: No no no... Don't send links to anything. State *in your own words* what isn't working, what is the error, what should be happening.

Comment: Saying cannot refer to an instance field while invoking a constructor for surname,gender and lesson and saying The field Human.name and age is not visible

Comment: Please read [ask] and then how to create a [mcve]. Apply those to your question by editing it (don't comment please).

Answer (score 0):

You defined a Teacher class, and its constructor.

```
Teacher(String na_,String sur_,int a,String g_,String le_);
```

but you are doing:

```
super Teacher(name,surname,age,gender);
```

and such a constructor is not defined in that class...

so you need to either overload the constructor and create the

```
Teacher(String na_,String sur_,int a,String g_);
```

or pass the args completely.

---

**PS**: In my Opinion a Retired_teacher  is a Teacher but with a `boolean` member set to false (active or not),

creating a new class for just a change in the members can be too much.